Не видит АКБ линукс минт
Подскажите почему не видит акб ноут?  
Прописал команду
$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BATO
  native-path:          (null)
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Thu 01 Jan 1970 03:00:00 MSK (1716265733 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  unknown
    warning-level:       unknown
    battery-level:       unknown
    percentage:          0% (should be ignored)
    icon-name:          '(null)'

выдало вот такую историю, я так понял что система думает, что у меня 0% акб
